# Accessing a CoreData entity between app versions, etc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, ios4

I inherited a project that uses CoreData for a certain type of data storage. I want to remove CoreData from the app and convert the data into a different format...

Over the course of developing other features, I had removed the CoreData framework from the app and the model declarations in such, not expecting to need to convert the old data.

But now I do need to convert the old data. So the first steps I took were to go back into source control, dig out the xcdatamodel files from the old version and plug them back into the app.

Then I went to an older version of the app, installed in on a device, created some data...

Then when I go back to the newer version of the app with CoreData "re-installed", I get a crash claiming that the data entity in question cannot be found in the managed object context. I triple checked spelling and syntax and it checks out.

I feel like maybe I'm missing some vital piece of configuration to make it recognize the xcdatamodel file that declare the entity.

Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a syntactical flaw that was causing the full context to not be loaded properly... when I changed that then everything loaded fine.

Sometimes these frameworks give the most misleading errors...

Answer (score 1):

What the core data schema versioned? Are you sure you have the right version? One thing you could try if all else fails is just to open the sqlite database file that core data uses for it's backing store and write your own migration routine.

Comment: +1 for noting that you could manually migrate data using SQLite directly.

Comment: I think it was versioned but I am confident I am using the right version. The XCDataModel between the two versions is byte for byte identical.. and it DOES work with the old version. It's just with the newer version of the app.. it can't seem to find the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add new entity after 'that' old version? If yes then you need to write migration code for new version.

Comment: No, the schema has not changed at all since the old version